# VBA Look for Duplicate, then assesses another cells value

Tags: vba, excel

I initially asked a question below.

Basically I want VBA to look at Column L:L. If the cell=program, and the cell below does not equal lathe I want the row above to be deleted. If the cell doesn't equal program continue looking until the end of the data.

Realized I needed to look at the data different, as I was losing rows that I needed to stay.

> New logic, which I think will still use some of the old program, but
>   it needed to be sorted using another column. I need the VBA to look at
>   column E:E. If the cell in the row below is a duplicate of the cell
>   above, then look at column L in that row to see if the cell says
>   Program. If so the cell below should be Lathe. If not lathe delete the
>   Program Row, If it is Lathe leave both rows. If the Cells in Column E
>   are not duplicates, continue looking. EX. If `E5=E6`, If not continue
>   looking. If yes Look at L5 to see if it say Program. If so look at L6
>   for Lathe. If not delete ROW5.

This I what I received that answered teh first question which I think will still get used

```
Dim rngCheck as Range
Dim rngCell as Range

Set rngCheck = Range("L1", "L" & Rows.Count - 1)

For each rngCell in rngCheck
    If rngCell.value = "Program" And rngCell.offset(1,0).value <> "lathe" then
        rngCell.offset(-1,0).EntireRow.Delete
    End if
Next rngCell
```

Comment: One note, you are iterating through the entire sheet, That is over 1 million iterations.  When deleting rows one at a time like you are, one should loop backwards.

Comment: Your description is a little unclear - you talk about "the cell below" but it's not clear below *what*...  It would help to clarify every reference with what it's relative to

Comment: My example for below was if E5=E6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it

```
For i = ThisWorksheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row to 2 step -1
    ' that row do you mean the duplicate or the original (I am using original)
    If ThisWorksheet.Cells(i, 5) = ThisWorksheet.Cells(i-1, 5) and _        
       ThisWorksheet.Cells(i-1, 12) = "Program" and ThisWorksheet.Cells(i, 12) <> "Lathe"
       ThisWorksheet.Rows(i-1).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: This functioned as I needed to, although I was asked for some more requirements which is going to slightly change my logic. Thank you for this,  I will probably have another question that I will make a new post for if I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

When deleting it is best to iterate from last to first.  If prevent you from skipping rows.

```
Sub RemoveRows()
    Dim x As Long

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")

        For x = .Range("E" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
            If .Cells(x, "E").Value = .Cells(x - 1, "E").Value And Cells(x - 1, "L").Value = "Program" Then
                .Rows(x).Delete
            End If
        Next

    End With

End Sub
```